# Taking or having taken?

Tags: sentence-construction, participles

> The athlete has been accused of ______ dope  to boost his performance.

a. To have taken
b. Having been taken
c. taking
d. having taken

Which option is correct? I'm confused in C and D

Comment: Taking is present tense and so implies ongoing activity, having taken is past tense and so the activity is no longer happening.   Also, boost not boast.

Comment: A and B don’t work in the example. C sounds most natural if you want to express that he takes dope on a regular basis. D tells that he no longer takes it, but he used to take it in the past.

Comment: @AydenFerguson Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker Okay

Answer (score 1):

A and B don’t work in the example. C sounds most natural if you want to express that he takes dope on a regular basis. D tells that he no longer takes it, but he used to take it in the past.